# find the area of a kite with integration

Tags: calculus, integration, area

A stunt kite has the shape in the diagram below:

[image]

How can I find the area using calculus integration.

Can anyone help me start this question, I am not looking for the full answer. I assume I only need to find half the area and multiply it by two.  I know how to find the area between $2$ curves but this is different because it is $4$ curves.

I would find the area of half the kite that is bisected by the $y$-axis but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is given, $f(-x)$ is symetric about $y$ axis. Here substitute $-x$ for the function in one side to see if they are symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right, you only have to calculate one side (here the right side $x>0$) and then multiple the result by two.

Your are interested in the are area between the graph $y=1/2x^2-2x+8$ and the graph $y=1/4x^2+x$. The are lies between $x=0$ and where the graphs hit each other at $$1/2x^2-2x+8=1/4x^2+x$$.
This leads to $x=4$ respective $x=8$ but your are only interrested in the first hitting point ($x=4$).

Thus you have to evaluate the integrals:

$$\int_0^4 \left[\left(1/2x^2-2x+8\right)-\left(1/4x^2+x\right)\right]dx$$

Comment: why do I ignore x = 8

Comment: because this would be the second intersection of your graphs which is not mentioned in your plot.

Comment: I make the answer 240 but the book gives ${26{2\over 3}}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By using the symmetry, the sought area is **twice**

> $$
> \int_0^b(0.5x^2-2x+8)dx-\int_0^b(0.25x^2+x)dx
> $$

with the convenient solution of
$$
0.5b^2-2b+8=0.25b^2+b
$$ that is $$b=4.$$

Answer (score 0):

You will need to solve for the point $n$ in the upper bound of the integrals below. It is the point where the functions you are given intersect.

$$2(\int_{0}^{n}.5x^{2}-2x+8 dx-\int_{0}^{n}.25x^{2}+x dx)$$

Then of course you can integrate to find a solution. Do you see why this will lead to a solution? The first integral is the area under the top curve of the kite, the second is the area under the bottom curve. So to find the shaded region in the photo we take the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use double integral:

$$2\bigg[\int\limits_{(x=-4)}^{(x=0)}\int\limits_{(y=0.25x^2-x)}^{(y=0.5x^2+2x+8)}1\text{dydx}\bigg]=2\cdot 13.3333$$

Notice that first you need to find the intesection point between $y=0.25x^2-x$ and $y=0.5x^2+2x+8$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

[image]

I would say $S = 2\int_{0}^{x_P} (y_2-y_1)\,dx$